# Excel - how to increment formula reference along a row

Tags: vba, excel

I have really long strings of text saved in roughly 1000 cells down Column A.

I have created the following formula (some VBA included for FindN), placed in cell B1:

`=MID($A1,FindN("978",$A1,1),13)`

I can copy this formula down Column B just fine. However, I also want to copy this formula across each row, so for example the formulas for the cells across the row should be as follows:

Cell C1: `=MID($A1,FindN("978",$A1,2),13)`

Cell D1: `=MID($A1,FindN("978",$A1,3),13)`

Cell E1: `=MID($A1,FindN("978",$A1,4),13)`

etc...

If I copy the formula in Cell B1 across the row, it will copy across `=MID($A1,FindN("978",$A1,1),13)` - but I need the "1" to increment by 1 each time.

I think I'd need to adjust the formula slightly, but a bit lost on how to do this...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I should clarify further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `CELL` formula to get current column number. Try something like this:

`=MID($A1,FindN("978",$A1,CELL("column";A1)+1),13)`

I dont have English Excel and im not sure first argument in `CELL` forumla is "column"

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Yep, it's "col" in my version of Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Use `COLUMN()` - it gives the column number of the current cell. You can offset this as required.

In this case for your incrementing number use `COLUMN() - 1`, so that in B you have 1, C; 2 etc.

Comment: this is better solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Sub Fill()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=MID($A1,FindN(" & _
                     Chr(34) & "978" & Chr(34) & _
                     ",$A1," & i - 1 & "),13)"
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```